# SwiftUI: Setting offset for View in TabView causes stuttering

Tags: swiftui, tabview, swiftui-tabview

I'm trying to create a parallax effect for a specific view in a `TabView`. The problem is that the view slightly stutters while being dragged.
That's why I created a small project to determine if the problem originates from my app or the `TabView`.
I've noticed that my test project also has a similar problem.
Is there a workaround to prevent this stuttering effect?
The stuttering effect is more pronounced on a real device (I tried it on the iPhone 14 Pro with iOS 17).

Below is my test project:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentIndex: Int = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
            ForEach(0..<10) { index in
                TabViewContentView(text: String(UUID().uuidString.prefix(Constant.prefixLength)), isVisible: index == currentIndex)
                    .tag(index)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
    
    private enum Constant {
        static let prefixLength = 7
    }
}

private struct TabViewContentView: View {
    private let text: String
    private let isVisible: Bool
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = .zero
    
    init(text: String, isVisible: Bool = true) {
        self.text = text
        self.isVisible = isVisible
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.blue.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .overlay(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                    Text(text)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .offset(x: offset)
                }
                .opacity(isVisible ? 1 : .zero)
            Color.green.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .tabViewOffsetListener { newOffset in
            var parallaxOffset: CGFloat = .zero
            parallaxOffset = isVisible ? newOffset * -Constant.parallaxMultiplier : newOffset
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                offset = parallaxOffset
            }
        }
    }
    
    private enum Constant {
        static let parallaxMultiplier = 0.7
    }
}

private struct TabViewOffsetViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    private let offsetHandler: (CGFloat) -> Void
    private let clearColorView = Color.clear
    
    init(offsetHandler: @escaping (CGFloat) -> Void) {
        self.offsetHandler = offsetHandler
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                GeometryReader { proxy -> Color in
                    let dragOffset = proxy.frame(in: .global).minX
                    offsetHandler(dragOffset)
                    return clearColorView
                }
            )
    }
}

public extension View {
    func tabViewOffsetListener(offsetHandler: @escaping (CGFloat) -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(TabViewOffsetViewModifier(offsetHandler: offsetHandler))
    }
}
```